# Multiply and add values in text area by element in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not that easy to explain, so let me paste a little code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        calculateSum();
         $(".txt").live("keydown keyup", function() {
            calculateSum();
         });
     });

     function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        // Iterate through each textboxes and add the values.
        $(".txt").each(function() {
            // Add only if the value is number.
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
               sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
            else if (this.value.length != 0){
               $(this).css("background-color", "red");
            }
        });
        $("#currentCost").html(sum.toFixed(2));
     }
</script>
```

First off, I'd like to update that code to use the most recent version of jQuery, since it only works with 1.5 I think. (currently, it will just add the values in all textareas and update a span element)

```
<td>
    <select name="struct[213]">
        <option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
        <option value="2" data-price="4000">A</option>
        <option value="3" data-price="6000">B</option>
        <option value="4" data-price="8000">C</option>
        <option value="7" data-price="15000">D</option>
        <option value="11" data-price="80000">E</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="4" class="txt"
        name="numUnits[213]" value="0">
</td>
```

That's one of the textareas, all follow a similar fashion, and what I'd like to do with them is multiply the data-price in the select by the number entered in the textarea (all textareas and selects have the same [] following the name element), and then I'd like all those products added together in the span #currentCost:

```
<td class="L1" width="175">
    Cost: <span class="redmoney" id="currentCost" name="currentCost">$0</span>
</td>
```

If that makes any sense...

Comment: The .live() method is deprecated (after jQuery 1.7). Use .on() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    calculateSum();
    //register change handler for input and select elements
    $(document).on("keyup, change", ".txt, select", function () {
        calculateSum();
    });
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".txt").each(function () {
        var value = $.trim(this.value);
        if (value.length && !isNaN(value)) {
            //find the select in the previous td and multiply the value
            sum += parseFloat(value) * ($(this).parent().prev().find('option:selected').data('price') || 0);
            //change back the color
            $(this).css("background-color", "");
        } else if (this.value.length != 0) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        }
    });
    $("#currentCost").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a8p87/)